# Get notified when some other application acquires wake lock

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, wakelock

I am wondering if the following is possible in android. I want to have my application do a certain task whenever the phone get awoken. Whenever some other application acquires a wake lock to do it's task, I want my application to do something of its own.

Can I get notified through an intent using a broadcast receiver about this event? If so, what will happen if that other application finishes before my task ends?

The reason I'm asking is that I don't want to wake the phone up to do my task and affect the battery life. I want to take the opportunity of the wake lock to do my thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use AlarmManager with RTC or ELAPSED_REALTIME  type.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC

The device is not woken up when your alarm goes off. the next time phone is awake your alarm is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I get notified through an intent using a broadcast receiver about this event?

No.

> The reason I'm asking is that I don't want to wake the phone up to do my task and affect the battery life.

Then don't wake up the phone. Follow nandeesh's suggestion and use a non-`_WAKEUP` alarm. You will *still* need a `WakeLock`, though, because the device may fall back asleep before you complete whatever your work is.